# Value synchronisation not working properly

Tags: c, arrays, loops, matrix, strcmp

**I have the full code in this link of my program; please read this, the code I have on here is long enough but not all of it: https://pastebin.com/NpspcJB8**

As part of my assessment, I am attempting to have my code "synchronise" an array index with another. The problem that occurs is that when I run parts of code repeatedly, the output does not change after I input a value, for instance:

```
case 'b':

    CaseBPrompt();

    for (t=0;t<350;t++) {
        int result2[350];
        result2[t] = strcmp(blankSpace, parkingSpace[t]); // determine if the value of parkingSpace is the same as strcmp "empty"
        Synchronise(t);

        if (result2[t] == 0) { // if value of parkingSpace == "empty"
            // use spaceNumber; sync int variable w/array index
            LevelPrint(t);

            strcpy(carCustomer[t], customerName);
            // copy value of car number to index
            strcpy(parkingSpace[t], carNumber); // omit array index to ensure this can run
            break; // required, as will print other available spaces otherwise
        }

    }
    printf("You will take %s's car\n", carCustomer[t]);
    printf("Please drive the car over to %c%d\n", level, spaceNumber[t][3]);
break;
```

`t` is an integer variable that I declared globally outside of `main`. The following are the contents of the functions I used in here:

```
void CaseBPrompt() {
    printf("You have chosen to park a customer's car \n");
    printf("Please input the customer's name, using _ in lieu of a space\n");
    scanf(" %s", &customerName);
    // assign customer's name to carNumber - new array?

    printf("Please input the values of the number plate\n");
    // ensure use %s, as collecting string, and so const char/char error won't occur
    scanf(" %s", &carNumber);

}
void LevelPrint(int n) {
    if (spaceNumber[n][3] <= 100) {
    level = 'A';
    // don't forget to write out complete matrix for spaceNumber!

    printf("There is an available space at parking space %c%d\n", level,spaceNumber[n][3]);
    // assign parkingSpace array index w/user input

    } else if (spaceNumber[n][3] > 100 && spaceNumber[n][3]<= 200) {
        level = 'B';
        spaceNumber[n][3]-=100; // display correct parking space at corresponding level
        printf("There is an available space at parking space %c%d\n", level,spaceNumber[n][3]);

    } else if (spaceNumber[n][3] > 200 && spaceNumber[n][3]<= 300) {
        level = 'C';
        spaceNumber[n][3]-=200; // display correct parking space at corresponding level
        printf("There is an available space at parking space %c%d\n", level,spaceNumber[n][3]);

    } else if (spaceNumber[n][3] > 300 && spaceNumber[n][3]<= 350) {
        level = 'D';
        spaceNumber[n][3]-=300; // display correct parking space at corresponding level
        printf("There is an available space at parking space %c%d\n", level,spaceNumber[n][3]);

    } 
}
void Synchronise(int a) {
    spaceNumber[a][3] = n+1; // synchronise w/parking space
    carCustomer2[a][3] = n+1; // synchronise w/car customer name
}
```

When I run the code, I receive this output:

```
empty
350
25
Please write car number (without spaces):
b

b
Valet options (press the corresponding letter to select):
a) Check available spaces
b) Park a customer's car
c) Retrieve a customer's car
q) Exit the program
Your choice: b
You have chosen to park a customer's car
Please input the customer's name, using _ in lieu of a space
b
Please input the values of the number plate
b
There is an available space at parking space A1
You will take b's car
Please drive the car over to A1
Valet options (press the corresponding letter to select):
a) Check available spaces
b) Park a customer's car
c) Retrieve a customer's car
q) Exit the program
Your choice: b
You have chosen to park a customer's car
Please input the customer's name, using _ in lieu of a space
b
Please input the values of the number plate
b
There is an available space at parking space **A1**
You will take b's car
Please drive the car over to **A1**
Valet options (press the corresponding letter to select):
a) Check available spaces
b) Park a customer's car
c) Retrieve a customer's car
q) Exit the program
Your choice: c
You have chosen to retrieve a customer's car
Please write their name, again with _ in lieu of a space:
c
Please write down what was on their number plate:
90jda
c's car is at **1**.
Valet options (press the corresponding letter to select):
a) Check available spaces
b) Park a customer's car
c) Retrieve a customer's car
q) Exit the program
Your choice:
```

The characters I surrounded with asterisks for the output are what concern me, since before I added code under `case 'c'`, the code under `case b` would print correctly. I am using DevC++, and I am wondering if there's anything wrong with my code.

When I chose to do option B again, the code would print A2, A3 and so on for each iteration before this, and what is meant to appear under option C output is the value of 149, since I preassigned a value of `90jda` under `parkingSpace[150][3]`.

The value under `parkingSpace` is meant to synchronise with `blankSpace` for `case 'b'`, to which it prints out that available space in its `for` loop. For `case 'c'`, `parkingSpace` is meant to synchronise with whatever index holds the same string as from user input `carNumber`, which is compared in the beginning of the `for` loop under `case 'c'`.

Comment: Do you really need such a huge amount of code and text to post in your question here?

Comment: Why are you declaring `result2` as an array? You only ever use one element of it.

Comment: Consider using an array of  `struct`s instead of multiple arrays.

Comment: I'm declaring it as an array because they'd handle the comparation result for each array value that is gone through in the loop.

Comment: @MarcMonis If you just use a single array of structs, instead of separate arrays, you don't need to synchronize anything. All the related data is together in one array element.

Comment: It's really hard to help without some explanation of what all these variables are. What's in `[3]` in all the arrays?

Comment: @Barmar `[3]` is to show the length of the string or integer

Comment: What is the variable `n` in the `Synchronize()` function? Do you really have a global variable with such a meaningless name? Where is the code that sets it?

Comment: Above the main function; I linked the full code under pastebin or else it would get excessively long. `n` is the function argument in `Synchronise`

Comment: `blankSpace` is a string with the value `"empty"`. I recommend that you read the pastebin link for the full context

Comment: You often access beyond the limits of the arrays. Ex you declare as `int spaceNumber[350][3]`, but you try to access `spaceNumber[a][3] = n+1;` That's an illegal index and will cause Undefined Behavior....Are you allowed to use `struct`s?

Comment: IDK if I'm allowed to use `struct`

Oh, and I think you might have helped to answer my question, sorry about that, but I'll check to see if it works.

Thank you @JohnnyMopp, I didn't realise this

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I managed to solve it, it was because of one of the values I declared in my array which were not identical; the program didn't return an error since both were declared as integer variables